# InputStream.read() unexpectedly returns number of bytes instead of -1

Tags: java

When I run `read()` in Eclipse and enter chars at the console followed by ENTER, the returned value is the number of bytes entered, not `-1`, though the string I enter into the console is terminated by ENTER, which as I understand generates end-of-stream condition..

The only explanation I can think of is that ENTER signals end-of-stream for the console itself, without being interpreted by `read()` as EOF

Comment: "enter" (I assume you mean a newline) doesn't end a stream in any way.

Comment: But the author of a highly renowned Java book says it does, and that's why I mentioned it!

Comment: I don't know the quote you are referring to; but it sounds like you have misunderstood what it says.

Answer (score 2):

> the string I enter into the console is terminated by ENTER, which as I understand generates end-of-stream condition

No, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not generate end-of-stream condition. Depending on your operating system, it is usually either a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

Moreover, `read` will return a number of bytes it reads on first call, even if you end console's stream. The second call, when the stream is already closed, will produce `-1`. This behavior is correct, otherwise your program would not receive the "tail end" of the data entered on the console just prior to stream termination.

Comment: Hi.. . I don't mean to be stubborn or anything, just trying to exploit every possible explanation that may be. Is it not possible that's some sort of intermittent end-of-stream, whereby a chunk of input into the console has filled up and buffering is complete for processing? That's different than the ultimate end-of-stream digested by read() and that concludes the stream.. ? I don't know.. what do you think?

Comment: @Searcherer You will not get a negative one until you have taken all the input from the buffer.